# Регулярное выражение java script

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

У меня была такая регулярка:

```txt
 /^(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:;|$))+$/
```

Она позволяет писать цифры в формате `7.1;8.2;9.3`, но мне бы хотелось добавить еще возможность ставить пробелы между числами после точки с запятой в таком формате: `7.1; 8.2; 9.3`.
Погуглив немного я выяснил что пробел это `\s` и у меня получилось это:

```txt
 `/^(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:;+\s|$))+$/`
```

Теперь принимает такой формат строки `7.1; 8.2; 9.3`, но не принимает такой `7.1;8.2;9.3`, а хотелось бы чтобы оба варианты были валидны, подскажите пожалуйста что я еще забыл, как это доделать?

Comment: `\s?` [демо](https://regex101.com/r/Xofjal/1)

Comment: спасибо выручил